# Image won't align to Center

Tags: html, css

I am using a CSS reset script causing the image to not center.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

### HTML

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="images/final2.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />
        <p>This is the first paragraph in the body of your new HTML file!</p>
            asdfas
    </body>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    /*width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; */
    z-index: -1; /* Ensure div tag stays behind content; -999 might work, too. */

    background-color:black;
}

.stretch {
    /*width:100%;
    height:100%;*/
    z-index:-1;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

### CSS Reset

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: is this all the css you have on page? because i see external files.
can you please post it on jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem

Comment: ah I have a css reset I forgot about

Comment: can you show your reset code?

Comment: I posted it.  Do you see what the issue is?

Comment: We really don't know exactly what it is you are trying to do. Oh, center the image, we get that, but the other choices you have made in your HTML & CSS are not really logical based on our experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Well..

use this css

```
.stretch {

    z-index:-1;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Check this demo.http://jsfiddle.net/hzZXV/1/

Comment: Excellent! Beautiful and Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image with div and set his width to the image width and center it with `margin: 0 auto;`

for example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/icon_book.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div>
```

Css

```
#wrapper {
   width:  image-width;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szt5U/)

Comment: Assuming that this should actually be a 'content' image and not a bg image..then this is fine.

Comment: I suspect the OP is new to this world and may not know the 'right 'way to go abut things. The fact that the are are no divs included and has resorted to positioning first would lead me to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Apply left 50% on class stretch:

```
.stretch{
/*width:100%;
height:100%;*/
z-index:-1;
position:fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `position: fixed;` with `margin: 0 auto;` so you have to use the way that you do for `position: absolute;` centering. Here is the way to do it:

```
.stretch {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: - img-width/2;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/FAFTW/